# WordPress: Redirect from [without www] to [www]

Tags: wordpress, redirect, web, settings

recently decided to change the address of my WordPress site with [without the www] to [www]. After several failed attempts with the .htaccess file I gave up and found out that by changing the address in the WordPress settings will work. Everything worked beautifully, so I made the same changes to my 16 other sites.

Today it turned out, that on one site is the redirects loop (http://seopinguin.info.pl/ version: http://www.seopinguin.info.pl/ works fine!).

I've tried:

1. removed the.htaccess file.
2. turned off all plugins
3. changed the default theme
4. updated everything to the latest version
5. reviewed the files if there's not any manual redirect like "header ( "http:// ... etc"
6. reviewed _options table that is everywhere a correct adress with www
7. reviewed  that everywhere in Settings are a correct adress with www

And ... nothing!

After testing here http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/ it turns out that the page redirects to itself (from without "www" to without "www").

As you type the address of the "www" it all works properly. All other sites work perfectly and redirect to the version of the "www".

Please help - I have no idea what more can I do.

Comment: It looks like it could be your server settings. Sometimes the different providers use a default with or without 'www' which can override your file settings.

Comment: I forgot to write: Before I started this topic, I asked the hosting provider and he told me that on the server side everything is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that it was probably a server problem. I changed the IP address of the website and everything started working. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Yea I knew it was. Glad you fixed it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd Check with your web host provider. They usually have options in their setting panel to control this sort of thing.

Comment: I forgot to write: Before I started this topic, I asked the hosting provider and he told me that on the server side everything is OK.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear you got it fixed!